# In react how can redirect to user from one domain to another domain without entering user credentials?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, cross-domain

I am new to reactjs, My question is How can I redirect user from one domain to another domain without entering the user credentials.

I have one application where user logged in with his credentials. Then there is some actions list. In that when user click on the link it redirect to new application. But again user has to enter his credentials to sign in the application. To avoid the agin sign in into the application what I have did is while click on the link I have attached the token parameter with `href` after redirecting to the new domain I get that token from URL by using 
 `queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)` then I hit the rest API to check whether token is valid or not, if valid then it redirect to the welcome page instead to show login page again.

Below is my code where I have achieved it but I dont think its a right approach to achieve this may be it will breaking the security.

This is my first application code:

```
    <a className="dropdown-item" 
    href=`http://localhost:3001/?token=${localStorage.getItem('my_token')}
   &userName=${item.name}` target="_blank">
    View Job
    </a>
```

and this one is my second application code where I am getting token from url:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
let myToken = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
if (myToken.token) {
  localStorage.setItem('access_token', myToken.token);
 }
}
```

I know this is not a right way to do the things. cause of that I am here to know how can I achieve that result.If anyone know what is the right way to do that things please guide me or give some example link where someone has done this thing.

If anyone still not understood the question please do the comment so that I can explain it in better way.

any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is related to React specifically. You wan't to use Single Sign On (SSO). Your approach is working but I'm not sure if it fullfills all OWASP criteria. There are some common practices around with integrating an invisible iframe from one SSO domain and use a cookie. This iframe can communicate with the surrounding parent. Maybe there are some more advanced approaches. Maybe this will help you: https://codeburst.io/building-a-simple-single-sign-on-sso-server-and-solution-from-scratch-in-node-js-ea6ee5fdf340

Comment: Is there any other method for SSO?